# Applet not finding KeyEvents or acquring focus

Tags: java, applet, focus

My Applet isn't ever acquiring focus. I run it in eclipse, or I toss it on my webserver, either way it doesn't ever acquire focus.

I'd understand if my drawing mechanism wasn't working, since I wrote that and I am still working out the kinks in it. But, I have a debug message that should be firing when I press a key, and a debug message that should be firing when I acquire focus. Neither ever fire.

It DOES display the context though. It just generates some random pictures and displays them.

What do I need to do to acquire focus and get my key events?

Here's the class. It has been slightly trimmed down, but not significantly.

```
public class ClientMain extends Applet implements KeyListener, FocusListener {

    private Image offscreen;

    private Image primary; // the main view screen

    private ClientContext context;

    public void init() {
        setSize(800,600);
        setFocusable(true);

        offscreen = createImage(800, 600);

        primary = createImage(530,450);

        // for testing purposes. This just creates a random context
        context = ClientContext.generateRandomContext(); 

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics buffer = offscreen.getGraphics();
        buffer.clearRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());

        drawPrimary(); 

        g.drawImage(offscreen, 0, 0, this);

    }

    private void drawPrimary() {
        Graphics g = primary.getGraphics();
        int w = primary.getWidth(null);
        int h = primary.getHeight(null);
        System.out.println("primary: " + w + " " + h);
        context.drawPrimary(g,w,h);
        offscreen.getGraphics().drawImage(primary,150,0,this);
    }

    public void update() {
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + e.getKeyCode());
        switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: context.up(); break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: context.down(); break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: context.left(); break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: context.right(); break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("got focus");

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        System.out.println("lost focus");

    }

}
```

Comment: No real reason to believe this helps, but still, i'd derive from JApplet.

Comment: @MBFG What benefits do you gain from JApplet over Applet?

Comment: JApplet is swing, Applet is awt. Awt uses heavyweight components (platform controls), swing liteweight (just java code). Might change the way events are processed.

Comment: Then you use Swing techniques. I've seen you answer many Swing related questions, so you should be more familiar with Swing components.

Comment: @camickr I am quite familiar with Swing, in fact the first prototype of this project was done in Swing. Then I thought about the future of the project and realized that, for the most part, it doesn't need swing OR awt really. Almost everything in it is simply displaying images on top of other images on top of other images.

Comment: `context = ClientContext.generateRandomContext();` W(TF) is that supposed to mean?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  And I would say that one huge advantage of using `JApplet` over `Applet` is that when asking questions, you might get answered by people that have actually made one (in the last 8 years).

Comment: @Andrew The problem was solved an hour ago. I can honestly say the only time I've ever seen you post ~anything~ is preaching about "SSCCE" (which, imo, is a horrible acronym, even if useful in most, but not all, cases.) I am quite familiar with what it takes to debug an application, and if one would have helped here, I would have made one, but it wouldn't have (and in fact didn't.) If you have no output, SSCCEs are fairly worthless, since it's just a matter of pouring over code. I solved this problem over an hour ago. I would have deleted it if cam hadn't had answered.

Comment: @glowcoder "I can honestly say the only time I've ever seen you post ~anything~ is preaching about "SSCCE""  So you can 'honestly say' that you *missed the source code I posted* 6 minutes prior to that comment? "(which, imo, .."  This has already been 'discussed to death' on other threads on other forums.  I felt no-one came up with a better alternative (certainly not one that conveyed everything that SSCCE does), so **it stays.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I feel pretty silly.

I never added a key listener. So it was grabbing the events, but it didn't do anything with them.

I just had to add this to my init()

```
addKeyListener(this);
```

... Doh!

Comment: +1  Thanks for reporting the solution.  (That comment is more for any newbie who might glance at this thread later.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about AWT. Why are you still writing AWT code? The only think I can suggest if that you should always invoke super.paint() when overriding a paint method.

If you do decide to write a Swing applet then you should be aware that the code is completely different, not just a matter of extending JApplet, since painting in Swing is completely different than painting in AWT. Maybe start with the [How to Make Applets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html) tutorial.

An applet in Swing is just like an application in Swing. YOu add components to the content pane of the applet. So if you want to do custom painting you create a custom panel for the painting and add it to the applet. The panel must be focusable in order for it to receive KeyEvents.

Answer (score 0):

(grumbles) I see you have already solved it, but I prepared this small Swing based example and now I'm going to post it.

```
// <applet code='GoodTouchApplet' width='400' height='400'></applet>
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GoodTouchApplet extends JApplet {

    JPanel gui;

    public void init() {
        gui = new JPanel();
        gui.setFocusable(true);
        KeyListener keyListener = new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                System.out.println(keyEvent);
            }
        };
        gui.addKeyListener(keyListener);

        setContentPane(gui);
    }

    public void start () {
        // Applets and focus are a 'mess'.  Best request it.
        gui.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}
```

Tested and confirmed working in a Java 6 SDK applet viewer & a recent version of FF running 1.6.0_24.